# Adding Ajax to Book navigation block

Tags: 7, ajax

I am using book navigation block which contains links to content of BOOK.I would like add ajax functionality to this links.

I tried adding use-ajax class to this links.But i was unsuccessful.

Please let me know how to ajaxify links of book navigation block

Thanks a lot for the help.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using drupal6(you haven't specified) then try the [AdvancedBookBlocks](http://drupal.org/project/advancedbookblocks) module. It is built on the ideas of the jquery menu module and could help you.

If you are on drupal7 there is a port of the drupal 6 module though still a sandbox project. I have tried it out and it works. You can find it [here](http://drupal.org/sandbox/nouriassafi/1576288)